# How to add extra column with values based on previous rows in Pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data frame:

```
'C1'|'C2'
 0  | x
 1  | x1
 1  | x2 
 2  | x3
 0  | y
 1  | y1
 2  | y2
 0  | z
 1  | z1
```

I need to create an extra column like this:

```
'C1'|'C2'|'C3'
 0  | x  | x
 1  | x1 | x
 1  | x2 | x
 2  | x3 | x
 0  | y  | y
 1  | y1 | y
 2  | y2 | y 
 0  | z  | z
 1  | z1 | z
```

Basically when ever I find 0 in the C1 column, I have to put in all the sub rows (until the next 0) the corresponding value from the C2 column.

I am new to Pandas and I read that I should avoid manipulating the data frame using iterations.

How can a get this result without iterating? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for mising values if not match condition with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) (`==`) and forward filling missing values by `ffill`:

```
df['C3'] = df['C2'].where(df['C1'].eq(0)).ffill()
print (df)
   C1  C2 C3
0   0   x  x
1   1  x1  x
2   1  x2  x
3   2  x3  x
4   0   y  y
5   1  y1  y
6   2  y2  y
7   0   z  z
8   1  z1  z
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this also:

```
df['C3']=df['C2'].astype(str).str[0]
print(df)
```